# Google SiteLinks Issue

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I've read the FAQs and searched the help center. 
My URL is: http://marcusvbsiqueira.com

Hello and good morning,

After some research and no solution found for my problem, i have decided to contact Google Support and to open a post into the Google Webmasters forum, so maybe someone can help me out.
The problem is that only one single page is shown as an internal link for my personal WebSite, the Photo Gallery page, although i have other pages just like this one, and they are all made using the same coding technic. 
If you search on Google for my name "Marcus V. B. Siqueira" or search my website "marcusvbsiqueira.com" you'll see that it shows my website, and just the Photo Gallery as a internal link. 
If any of you, can check out by inspecting element over the site, and see if there's something weird with the other pages, i would appreciate it, because i have checked more than one time, and all seems fine for the links. I have on the top of the WebSite, some links for the other pages, as can you see, but only one of those are being indexed. I'm also sure i have not put anything on the robots.txt that would exclude any other page from my WebSite. 
The site is XHTML 4.1, with none HTML 5 (For W3C Validation), and the only way to access other pages on the WebSite is by cliking on the Internal links at the top of the page.
I hope someone can help me out.

Thank you,

Marcus Siqueira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you can do nothing (special) about that and they (Google) won't help you.
Work on your site, get more Traffic and get especially more Brand-Traffic.
If Google hasn't enough data or if they don't have a feeling that somebody is interested in you, then they have no reason to show more Sitelinks than they do right now.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If [...] we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

Matt Cutts: How are sitelinks generated?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpR34uwujeY

> Be patient and get more Visitors to the other URLs.